Convert multiple MYSQL rows to only one array column
I have a simple database with the user and the country tables.
Which user belongs to only one country.
Which country has a list of users.
Right now Im using group_concat (code below) and its working in a "manual" way where Im suppose to build the array myself in PHP.
That's my output right now:



country
userFromCountry




Brazil
John /  Richard /   Robert



But I wonder if there's a better way to bring the data as an "automatic" array, something like that



country
userFromCountry




Brazil
[John] [Richard] [Robert]



I could make it "manually" with concat but when I try with JSON_ARRAY i have a "more than one row returned" error.
Fiddle example:
https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=a2bede84-5293-4366-aa84-ff285322b92a
Thank you

I'm confused why you would do this. Why not just SELECT name FROM user WHERE country_id = <whatever> and then fetchAll() or equivalent?

It's not clear if you mean "PHP array" or something else.

@AlexHowansky, agreed, but for this very particular case I need this  specific structure (1:n)

@Olivier i need this in the MYSQL layer

Topical content: How to create a three dimensional array from sql query PHP and How do I retrieve results as multidimensional array from mySQL and PHP? Return MySQL query as multidimensional array and How to populate PHP 3D array from MySQL and How to make multidimensional array from mysql

You just need to use JSONARRAY_AGG aggregation function. Also using JOIN the tables is more efficient way to achieve desired result, so I can advise next query:
SELECT country.name as country, JSON_ARRAYAGG(user.name) AS userFromCountry
FROM `country`
JOIN `user` ON user.country_id=country.ID
GROUP BY country.name;
  

Try the SQL code here

Does it handle the conversion to php array? If not, only needs to add $var = json_decode($query['users], true)

Is this a new insight on Stack Overflow or is this possibly a duplicate question?

thanks, it worked. It was not working before because of my apache/mysql version. But now it is working. Sorry for my delay, i lost my computers the last days. Thanks
